# TextBlock is not updating using ViewModel's property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am working on a small wpf application, i am showing status using a textblock and for achieving this i have bind a property from a view model. I have mapped everything despite this UI is not showing any value. I am pasting code as below.

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public LogViewModel LogTextVm { get; set; }
```

**ViewModelLocator.cs**

```
App thisApp = (App)Application.Current;
public ViewModelLocator()
{
    thisApp.LogTextVm = new LogViewModel();
}
```

**LogViewModel.cs**

```
public class LogViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _logText { get; set; }
    public string LogText
    {
        get => _logText;
        set
        {
            if(_logText!=value)
            {
                _logText = value;
                OnPropertyChnaged("LogText");
            }
        }
    }
    private void OnPropertyChnaged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyApplication.ViewModels"
<Window.Resources>
    <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"/>
</Window.Resources>

<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding LogText, Mode=TwoWay}" DataContext="{Binding LogViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
                       FontFamily="segoe UI" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="White" />
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private App thisApp = (App)Application.Current;
public MainWindow()
{
     InitializeComponent();
}
private async void CallGraphButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     thisApp.LogTextVm.LogText = "Status : Loading data ...";
}
```

Can anyone help me, where i am doing mistake?

Comment: TextBlocks `Foreground` is `White`, unless the background colour is different colour, you won't see the text! Remove the style for the TextBlock and keep it standard to see if that's the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assign `MainWindow.DataContext` with the same `LogViewModel` instance that is created by `ViewModelLocator`

`DataContext="{Binding LogViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"` can it create a new instance of the `ViewModelLocator` (and therefore thus new `LogViewModel`) ?

Please put the breakpoint at the `thisApp.LogTextVm = new LogViewModel();` line and check is it executed twice?

**UPD** VS output shows binding error for your code

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'LogViewModel' property not found on 'object' ''ViewModelLocator' (HashCode=37320431)'. BindingExpression:Path=LogViewModel; DataItem='ViewModelLocator' (HashCode=37320431); target element is 'StackPanel' (Name=''); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object')
```

You are binding to the wrong names unfortunately. To fix the binding I had to change the code as below:

ViewModelLocator

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        App thisApp = (App)Application.Current;
        LogTextVm = new LogViewModel();
        thisApp.LogTextVm = LogTextVm;
    }

    public LogViewModel LogTextVm { get; set; }

}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel  DataContext="{Binding LogTextVm, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
        <TextBlock  Text="label:" />
        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding LogText, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Button Content="click" Click="Button_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

`DataContext="{Binding LogTextVm, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">` creates `ViewModelLocator` instance and binds `StackPanel.DataContext` to the `ViewModelLocator.LogTextVm` property.

The `<TextBlock Text="{Binding LogText, Mode=TwoWay}" />` binds to the `LogText` for the current DataContext (which is `LogTextVm` property value)

Comment: Thank you for looking into my issue, i have checked by putting breakpoint on thisApp.LogTextVm=new LogViewModel(); this line executed one time when application start loading MainWinodw page. I executed application by removing line DataContext="{Binding LogViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" as well but in that case i am getting runtime exception on thisApp.LogTextVm.LogText = "Status : Loading data ..."; exception: null object

Comment: @AshishJain is it because of `Foreground="White"` ? Do you see any text for textblock ? Seems that text is painted in white color on white background

Comment: I have kept foreground white because the background is DarkBlue of it's container StackPanel.

Comment: @AshishJain put the breakpoint on `OnPropertyChnaged("LogText");` line please. Is it executed? do you have subscriber for `PropertyChanged` event?

Comment: Yes, it executed, i had put breakpoint on it. and it was executed.

Comment: @AshishJain I've built the sample from your code. The problem is that `PropertyChanged` is null and is not called

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205422/discussion-between-ashish-jain-and-oleksa).